# What color suns has Superman encountered, and what effects did they have on him?

Tags: dc, superman, powers, krypton

We all know that under a red sun - like Krypton's - [Superman is just Regularman](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13490/in-the-dc-comics-universe-what-happens-to-earthlings-under-a-red-sun), and a yellow sun - like ours - [gives him his superpowers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/21458/is-superman-really-super-compared-to-other-kryptonians/21462#21462).

What about other colors?  Which colors has he encountered, and what did each of these stars do to him?